# Pull Request Lists and the set of approvers from BITBUCKET SERVER API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is it possible to get the List of all pull request with the details like the date when it was raised, the Person who raised it and the list of all the approvers from the BITBUCKET SERVER using the REST APIs

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, You can fetch the list of Pull requests along with all the other details like who raised it, when it was raised and who are the reviewers using the following API,

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.4.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp285

You will have the following as response,

```
{
"size": 1,
"limit": 25,
"isLastPage": true,
"values": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "version": 1,
        "title": "Talking Nerdy",
        "description": "It’s a kludge, but put the tuple from the database in the cache.",
        "state": "OPEN",
        "open": true,
        "closed": false,
        "createdDate": 1359075920,
        "updatedDate": 1359085920,
        "fromRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/feature-ABC-123",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "toRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "locked": false,
        "author": {
            "user": {
                "name": "tom",
                "emailAddress": "tom@example.com",
                "id": 115026,
                "displayName": "Tom",
                "active": true,
                "slug": "tom",
                "type": "NORMAL"
            },
            "role": "AUTHOR",
            "approved": true,
            "status": "APPROVED"
        },
        "reviewers": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "jcitizen",
                    "emailAddress": "jane@example.com",
                    "id": 101,
                    "displayName": "Jane Citizen",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "jcitizen",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "lastReviewedCommit": "7549846524f8aed2bd1c0249993ae1bf9d3c9998",
                "role": "REVIEWER",
                "approved": true,
                "status": "APPROVED"
            }
        ],
        "participants": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "dick",
                    "emailAddress": "dick@example.com",
                    "id": 3083181,
                    "displayName": "Dick",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "dick",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": false,
                "status": "UNAPPROVED"
            },
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "harry",
                    "emailAddress": "harry@example.com",
                    "id": 99049120,
                    "displayName": "Harry",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "harry",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": true,
                "status": "APPROVED"
            }
        ],
        "links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://link/to/pullrequest"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"start": 0 }
```