# Bitbucket migration from local server to cloud: What about pull requests and comments?

Tags: continuous-integration, migration, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-cloud

My organization are planning to migrate from a local Bitbucket server to bitbucket.org. The only major obstacle so far has been that the server-to-cloud migration path only migrates repository data (source code, tags, branches), not metadata (pull requests and comments, among other things).

The [migration guide](https://support.atlassian.com/migration/docs/plan-your-bitbucket-server-to-cloud-migration/?_ga=2.10837364.1350135032.1597021693-1498980259.1557432741) says:

> There's no supported method for migrating ... repository metadata
> like pull request history and comments.

This warning is repeated in the [FAQ](https://support.atlassian.com/migration/docs/faqs-about-migrating-to-bitbucket-cloud/).

Our PRs and comments are important to us, for historical purposes. We can work around most of the other limitations. However, the pull requests are a critical component for us.

My research turned up the following two posts on SO:

- [Fetch All Pull-Request Comments Via Bitbucket REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306295/fetch-all-pull-request-comments-via-bitbucket-rest-api)
- [Pull Request Lists and the set of approvers from BITBUCKET SERVER API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594575/pull-request-lists-and-the-set-of-approvers-from-bitbucket-server-api)

If we were migrating just one repository, with a short history, we might be able to synthesize a solution from these posts. However, we have multiple repositories, some with years of history behind them.

Does anyone have a solution for this yet? That is, a way to migrate the PRs and comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether to update the question or simply provide an answer, so here's the answer.

Atlassian have finished their Bitbucket Cloud Migration Assistant. The release version of the Migration Assistant copies the metadata as well as the data. That is, pull requests and comments are migrated along with the source.

Here's the link to the [Migration Assistant](https://www.atlassian.com/migration/resources/bitbucket-migration-assistant). If the link goes stale, you can simply search for "bitbucket cloud migration assistant".